# If Statement Not Working Properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, if-statement, timer, nstimer

Whenever the value of "_currentField" (which is a text field with number formatter) is greater then or equal to 1000 I want "_congrats" (which is a panel) to show up and when its less than 1000 I want "_errormsg" (another panel) to show up. Every time I enter in any value the only thing that pops up is "_errormsg". What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)onTimer:(NSTimer*)aTimer {

    if ([_currentField.stringValue integerValue] >= 1000)

    {
        [_congrats orderFront:(id)self];
        [_progIndicator stopAnimation:(id)self];
    } 

    else { 
        [_errormsg orderFront:(id)self];
        [_progIndicator stopAnimation:(id)self];

        }

    }
```

Comment: Of what class is currentField?

Comment: Sorry! I should of mentioned that. Its a text field.

Comment: How is the number entered?  For example if it's typed as `1,000` with a comma then the parser may not be smart enough to consider this a number and it will return zero.

Comment: Use `[currentField.text intValue]` instead.

Comment: Yes, it automatically changes it to have a comma because it is a Text Field with Number Formatter.

Comment: Using `intValue` had no effect. :(

Comment: http://www4.picturepush.com/photo/a/8736832/img/8736832.png

Comment: The flexible formatting is the problem, then; I've added an Answer below.

Comment: Also; please rename this question to something more specific, e.g. something about text fields and numerical values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a formatter you need to ask the formatter to resolve the value.

The `formatter` method of `NSCell` (that `NSTextFieldCell` inherits from) returns the formatter object.  The `numberFromString:` method of the `NSNumberFormatter` returns the appropriate numerical value.

In this case, pass in the *string* value of the text field to the formatter's `numberFromString:` and you should see things like `1,000` turn into `1000` (as an integer).